# Android Menu does not inflate

Tags: android, menu

I am pulling my hairs out in trying to get menu to infate on my main activity but to no avail.

I am using Android Studio and the design view showed that the XML menu items are rightfully defined.

However, when I run the codes either in the phone(running Android 4.4.2) or emulator, the menu items are not showing up. Nothing happens when I press on the menu.

Any enlightenment will be most welcome.

Menu XML - my.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Option1"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Option2"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Option3"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Option4"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="Option5"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/item6" android:title="Option6"></item>
</menu>
```

Activity Class - myActivity.java

```
package com.example.mymenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
   return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(this, " " +
                    "Option1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Option3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item4:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Option4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item5:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Option5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.item6:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Option6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Layout File

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It looks ok to me.. just clean your project..

Comment: Did as you suggested, still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem.
My phone has a menu button, and pressing that button will display the menu list.

I tried with a newer phone that does not have the menu button, and the menu shows up within the action bar.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you must have created my.xml in layout folder .Create my.xml in menu folder.

Answer (score 0):

Cross check if the menu.xml is in menu folder and not any other res folder like layout.
Trying to inflate it in action bar?
If yes, then try using the following code in the menu.xml

`android:showAsAction="always"`

Refer : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Hi! Adding showAsAction=always will give me the first item on the action bar, but no click it doesn't gets me to rest of items been listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi try this if you want to display it in Actionbar.

  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_overflow"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
      <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Option1"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Option2"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Option3"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Option4"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="Option5"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item6" android:title="Option6"></item>
     </menu>
 </menu>
```

Comment: Ok! Did as you suggested, in addition to following the instructions in the action bar documents. In your suggested modification , the app: would refer to my application name. I got as far as getting the first item to show up on the action at, but not the rest of items.

Comment: Adding android:showAsAction="never" inside every Item will work!! Eg: <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Option1" android:showAsAction="never">   </item>